# DNS Server, DHCP Client and Server works fine, but request time out occurs when using MikroTik as an access point for a modem

Tags: wifi, mikrotik

I use 2 Mikrotik wireless router, the first one is connected to modem and it works perfectly (SSID: `server-one` (hidden)).

Second router ID:

ether1: `192.168.1.1`

wlan1: `dhcp-client`

wlan2: `192.168.2.1`

SSID: `skywifi`

Then, i tried to configure the second router. I set wlan1 to connect to `server-one`, as a station and dhcp client and received `192.168.50.124` as its IP, `192.168.50.254` as its gateway.

I set wlan2 as an ap-bridge, and set it as dhcp server. Then I create a static route to `0.0.0.0/0` through `192.168.50.254`.

Connection OK, DNS to device connecting `skywifi` works perfectly, i can `nslookup google.com`. The problem is, when i tried to `ping google.com`, it always give `request time out` reply. (Note that I also tried to ping another host too (`Wikipedia`,`Yahoo`, etc). The result is also `request time out`.

Any idea why this things happened?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The first router has no idea that it's supposed to NAT for the second router's clients, nor does it have any route to their IP addresses. As far as it's concerned the IP addresses the second router assigns to its clients are foreign to it, reachable only through its default route to the Internet, and it has no idea they belong on its LAN interface.

I wouldn't suggest a setup like this in the first place. Without knowing your exact requirements, it's hard to suggest a more sensible setup. But having a router NAT for more than one LAN is more complex than you probably need or want.

Networks with more than one LAN IP range, more than one router, and unbridged WiFi networks are complex. They should be set up by people who understand IP routing and the limitations of WiFi client connections. I'd suggest hiring a competent consultant who can ask you the right questions and ensure your design will do what you really need it to while avoiding pitfalls like double NAT, relaying WiFi on the same channel that halves bandwidth, or fake, unreliable WFi bridging.

Answer (score 0):

You also must activate NAT on second router...

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat out-interface=wlan1 action=masquerade
```